# ReadProcessMemory returning incorrect value

Tags: winapi, windbg, breakpoints, readprocessmemory

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int f(int x)
{
    return x+1;
}

// using vs 2019 debug|x86
int main()
{
    // visual studio's creates a label for f, which eventually jumps to it's implmentation.
    // the jump instruction is E9, then an offset to the implementation.
    // this calculates the actual address of f, by getting f+5(the length of the jump instruction)+the jump offset
    unsigned char *fAddr = (unsigned char*)f + 5 + *(int*)((char*)f + 1);

    printf("printing f bytes (pid %d at 0x%" PRIXPTR "):\n", GetCurrentProcessId(), fAddr);
    int fLen = 0x45; // for me, function size was 0x42
    for (int i = 0; i < fLen;)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10 && i < fLen; ++j)
            printf("%02X ", fAddr[i++]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The above code basically prints the code bytes of `f`.

Now if I put a software breakpoint inside `f`, that byte value changes to 0xCC.
And this will be reflected when `main` prints `f`.

I would expect that when calling ReadProcessMemory on the address of the breakpoint I would also get 0xCC instead of the original byte value.
This is indeed what happens when I set the breakpoint using Visual Studio.
However, when I set the breakpoint with WinDbg, ReadProcessMemory returns the original byte value.

1. Does anyone know why this happens and what in WinDbg is different than Visual Studio? After all, they both set software breakpoints.
2. Is there a way to see what the real value of a memory address is?

Edit:
Here's is the code I used to call ReadProcessMemory:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int *fPid;
    int *fAddr;
    printf("Please enter the pid of f (upper case hex digits, no 0x): ");
    scanf("%X", &fPid);
    printf("Please enter the address of f (upper case hex digits, no 0x): ");
    scanf("%X", &fAddr);

    printf("printing f bytes (pid 0x%X at 0x%X):\n", fPid, fAddr);

    HANDLE process;
    if ((process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, fPid)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        printf("OpenProcess error: %d\n", err);
        char cmd[100];
        sprintf(cmd, "net helpmsg %d", err);
        system(cmd);
        return 1;
    }
    int fLen = 0x45;
    unsigned char *buf = malloc(fLen);
    if (!ReadProcessMemory(process, fAddr, buf, fLen, NULL))
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        printf("ReadProcessMemory error: %d\n", err);
        char cmd[100];
        sprintf(cmd, "net helpmsg %d", err);
        system(cmd);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < fLen;)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10 && i < fLen; ++j)
            printf("%02x ", buf[i++]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

As for the breakpoint, in VS I just put a breakpoint on `return x+1`.
In WinDBG, I used `bp cpp_exe!f+20`, assuming the module (exe) name is `cpp_exe`.

Comment: If you're interested, I got to this when trying to set breakpoints in the .net runtime. However, the runtime itself occasionally patches it's own code at runtime, and then asserts that the code bytes are as expected, which of course fails if there's a breakpoint. See: [link](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/5147) for example

Comment: 0xcc is the INT3 instruction, universally used by debuggers to set a breakpoint.  When code instruction lands on it, the OS generates an exception that the debugger handles.  Windbg as well afaik.  But it wouldn't set the breakpoint on the JMP stub generated by incremental linking.  Hard to see directly, when you ask for a disassembly then it pretends that the original byte is still there.  Technically there is another way to do it, the processor also supports breakpoints in hardware.  But it only supports three of them and a debugger favors them to set data breakpoints.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm aware of what you wrote. It's not the point though. As I wrote, when I print the bytes of `f` from the `main` function, I can indeed see 0xCC, which confirms that a software breakpoint is being used. I also get this result when using ReadProcessMemory, as long as the debugger is VS. My question is: why does ReadProcessMemory work differently when WinDBG is debugging?

Comment: Can you tell us how you set the breakpoint in WinDbg? There are several ways of doing so. Also, I'd like to see the implementation using `ReadProcessMemory`. I'm too lazy to implement it myself ;-)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Sure :)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Actually, while testing the code for you to reproduce, I think I figured it out. Will post soon.

Comment: The 0xCC is removed while the program is broken into the debugger and replaced when execution resumes. If you never resume execution, then you will never see the 0xCC.

Comment: @RaymondChen You're right. I've figured it out by now. Do you have any idea why WinDBG does that while VS doesn't?

Comment: Leaving the breakpoint in memory when stopped makes it harder to dump memory and disassemble code, since you have to change the 0xCC byte back to the original value before displaying/disassembling it. I'm surprised VS leaves the byte patched when stopped.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I've figured it out.

When debugging with WinDBG and the debgugee is running, ReadProcessMemory returns the correct values (meaning I can see the 0xCC bytes).
However, when the debuggee is in break mode, than ReadProcessMemory returns the original byte values.

VS on the other hand, always returns the correct value (0xCC bytes, whether running or in break mode).

So I guess whenever WinDBG breaks, it actually removes all the software breakpoints, which are then reinstated as soon as you continue the application.
It's an interesting approach, I guess, but at least it makes sense.

Comment: ReadProcessMemory does nothing special. There is no correct or incorrect value. It returns what is there. The point is that different debuggers behave differently.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right. Could have chosen better wording. Maybe will edit later.